# How to maintain information from a database on a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I'm writing some not very complicated web application using servlets and jsp but there's some issue I still couldn't resolve.
On the [jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nra9.png) I've got multiple forms filled out with information retrieved from a database. Also there's several commands that modify this information (add, delete, submit, clear). If I click the "Add" button a request is sent to the servlet which invokes some of DAO methods and forwards the request to the same jsp page with updated "dishes list". It seems that all works just fine but what the hell should I do with the other forms (like the menu) cause this information is being removed after refreshing.
What is the best way to maintain all that information on the page? Should I send all that stuff with every command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Post/Redirect/Get pattern. More information can be found here: http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/08/20/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-spring-mvc/

Post

1. Initiate POST request with modified data.
2. Servet is processing request and updating database.

Redirect

1. Servlet is sending redirect to user browser.

Get

1. User browser is creating http get request.
2. Servlet is processing request and getting required data from database.
3. Response with latest data is sent back to the user.

Comment: Oh gosh. This seems like an adequate solution. Thanks!